# I can install my plugin in localhost but not in my server

Tags: plugin-development, installation, activation

Well, I finished my first plugin in WordPress but I have a little problem.

My plugin have the next code

```
add_action('my-plugin/my-plugin.php','rating_install');
add_action('admin_menu','rating_add_option');

function rating_install(){        
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."rating";
    $create = "CRETA TABLE ".$table_name." ( "
            . "id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
            . "url TINYTEXT NOT NULL, "
            . "descripcion TINYTEXT NOT NULL ) ";    
    $wpdb->query($create);
}

function rating_uninstall(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."rating";
    $drop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".$table_name;
    $wpdb->query($drop);
}

add_action('activa_rating/my-plugin.php','rating_install');
add_action('desactiva_rating/my-plugin.php','rating_uninstall');
```

And it's works in localhost when I active my plugin, but when I upload the plugin to my server this code isn't work, like it's doesn't exists. Don't create my table in the database.

I'm see the privilege in the database and I've all the privileges.

Comment: I think you have the Wrong action names in your `add_action` calls. you should use `register_activation_hook` and `register_deactivation_hook` or maybe `register_uninstall_hook`.

Comment: i think you used creta it should be create

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'rating_install');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'rating_uninstall');

function rating_install(){        
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."rating";
    $create = "CRETA TABLE ".$table_name." ( "
            . "id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, "
            . "url TINYTEXT NOT NULL, "
            . "descripcion TINYTEXT NOT NULL ) ";    
    $wpdb->query($create);
}

function rating_uninstall(){
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."rating";
    $drop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".$table_name;
    $wpdb->query($drop);
}
```